# Accessing FCM message logs

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having trouble figuring out whether or not FCM keeps logs of sent FCM push notifications, and if so, how to access them. I'm having intermittent issues with sending push notifications from an FCM server to an iphone app, and would love to be able to see at what stage the push is failing.

I found the below documentation that suggests that these logs should be kept somewhere:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en
*("You can look up messages sent through Firebase Cloud Messaging with a registration token or message ID.")*

However, I can't seem to figure out how to access them. Since my app is currently iOS only, I don't have an app in the Google Play Developer console, and my firebase console doesn't seem to contain any such logs. However, based on the possible message statuses in the documentation above (e.g. *Accepted, sent to APNS*), it seems like google / firebase should store message logs sent to iOS as well as to Android.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Yeah this is an issue for iOS only developers, however what you can do is create a Play Developer Account and then add an Android app. You will be able to diagnose messages even if they are not sent to another app.

Comment: I added an android app, but it seems like I actually need to publish something to the play store before I get a message log - am I misunderstanding how this works?